# Music bot volume only goes down, but not up

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I have a command named `volume` that can adjust the output volume of my music bot. This is how I defined the function:

```
@commands.command(aliases=['sound', 'vol'])
async def volume(self, ctx, vol: float):

    volume = vol / 100

    if vol > 100 or vol < 1:
        embed = discord.Embed(description='Please chose a volume level from 1 to 100', color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return

    try:
        self.voice.source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(self.voice.source, volume=volume)
    except Exception as e:
        error = str(e)
        if "'Music' object has no attribute 'voice'" in error:
            embed = discord.Embed(description='There isn\'t an audio volume to adjust.',
                                  color=discord.Color.red())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            return

    embed = discord.Embed(description=f'Successfully set the volume to **{int(vol)}%**.', color=discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

When I play a song and I do `p!volume 70`, the volume does go down from a bit. But when I try to make the volume go up again, by doing `p!volume 100`, the volume stays the same. Basically, I can only slide the volume down, but not up.

Why is that? And how can I fix this?

Comment: It might be expecting percentage transformation: 0.5 or 50 to lower the volume by fifty percent, 1 or 100 to stay the same, 1.5 or 150 to higher the volume by fifty percent

Comment: So technically I don't have to do `vol / 100`? I can just do `vol`?

Comment: I don't know the library so I can only infer, but IF the command is expecting a percentage of amplification and you're giving it a value etween 0 and 100 it will only go lower...

Comment: Oh I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!

```py
@client.command(name="volume")                          
async def volume(ctx, volume: float):                   
    voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)  

    if 0 <= volume <= 100:                              
        if voice.is_playing():                          
            new_volume = volume / 100                   
            voice.source.volume = new_volume            
        else:                                           
            await ctx.reply("#")   
    else:                                               
        await ctx.reply("#")

    await ctx.reply(f"Volume: {volume}")
```

It's the same exact code, but this time `PCMVolumeTransforme`r is not instantiated here. It's instantiated in the line that define the song to be played:

```py
discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url))
```

Before, this was just like this:

```py
discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url)
```

`FFmpegPCMAudio` doesn't have `volume` attribute.

For some mysterious reasons this worked and the other code didn't work.